# Multiuser Telegram bot Ruby

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, rubygems, telegram, telegram-bot

I need to make a multiplayer bot with deep condition tree for each user.
Need multiple users to be able to use the bot at the same time. And their sessions do not interrupt each other.
How to create async(or i don't need async?) telegram bot ruby? Or other ways to realize my task.
I am using gem telegram-bot-ruby.
In the code below you will see a very simple example of how I try to build a bot. But everything breaks down if several users start using the bot at the same time.
Or is my problem with the wrong approach and implementation?
**I will be very grateful for your advice.**

```
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|

  bot.listen do |message|
    case message.text
    when '/start'
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Hello, enter name:")

      bot.listen do |message2|
        @name = message2.text
        break
      end

      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Nice to meet you #{@name},now input age")

      bot.listen do |message3| 
        @age = message3.text
        break
      end

    when '/stop'
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Bye")

    else
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Enter /start ")
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried looking at examples of telegram ruby bot implementations on github, googled, but still haven't figured it out. I write the bot as a standalone script. I don't use rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use multiuser bot you can wrap listener code with thread

```rb
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
  bot.listen do |message|
    Thread.start(message) do |message|
      # make stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Every session will work in separate thread

---

And other things as idea for you:

- create some entity (message handler), instantiate it inside thread, incapsulate message checks inside this handler
- use database to storage state of every user "tree"

Comment: You don't need new `bot.listen` to interact with user. Just single as some kind of entrypoint. And some database to store user state and answers